# Django cms - Plugin in Plugin relation

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am using django cms 3.5.x.

I try to create a new plugin that contains other plugins, but not over the "normal" way (`allow_child=True`).

I would like to say `PluginBox` should contain two `PluginText` and another plugin `PluginContainer` should contain 4 `PluginText`.

I also want to render the first `PluginText` of box inside a div and the second one inside a span.

For example:

```
class Box(CMSPlugin):
    text1 = TextPlugin
    text2 = TextPlugin


<div class="box">

    <div>
        {% render text1 }
    </div>

    <span>
        {% render text2 }
    </span>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this is worthwhile reading for you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-cms-developers/vtsdrMWnUFA